# How can I drag a rect over a path in D3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have to drag a rect element following an arc path. How can I do it ?

Here you can see my code: https://jsfiddle.net/hsspve49/

```
var drag = d3.drag().on("drag", function () {
            var rect = d3.select(this);
            var theta = Math.atan2(d3.event.y - height/2, d3.event.x - width/2) * 180 / Math.PI


            rect
                .attr("x", d3.event.x-rect.attr("width")/2)
                .attr("y", d3.event.y-rect.attr("height")/2)
                .attr('transform', `rotate(${theta + 90}, ${d3.event.x}, ${d3.event.y})`)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this can be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38249275/drag-along-path-in-d3

Comment: Yes ... but quitly difficult. Isn't there something more direct ? For example a d3 function to call e.g. .. rect.attach(arc) .. Idk .. something similar